# Calculating Volatility in the Avellaneda and Stoikov Model

Tags: volatility, market-making

I'm looking to understand the approach for calculating volatility (σ^2) within the context of the Avellaneda and Stoikov market-making model. I have a few specific questions on this topic:

Return Type: Should I be using log returns or simple returns for this calculation? What's the standard practice in this context?

Data Interval: Given that I have order book data, what's the typical interval at which returns are measured? Are we looking at high-frequency intraday intervals or something more extended, like daily returns?

Annualization: Once the volatility is computed, is the result typically annualized?

Price Influence: I've observed that for a given volatility value, changing the stock price doesn't affect the spread. This seems counterintuitive. Could someone help me understand why the spread remains the same despite varying stock prices?
[image]